# GWTP Gatekeeper and the UserService

Tags: gwt, gwt-platform

I am having a problem using the Gatekeeper feature of GWTP. 
Following the example [gwtp-sample-tab](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/source/browse/#hg%2Fgwtp-samples%2Fgwtp-sample-tab%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Fgwtplatform%2Fsamples%2Ftab%2Fclient%253Fstate%253Dclosed) I have created the client code. But now I am still wondering how to notify the client side if the user has successfully logged in? (I am using the Google UserService.)

Could anybody please provide me a litte example?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if i correctly understand your question because GWTP gatekeppers exists just for security purposes(block admin pages from other users or something similar). Annotate presenters with `@UseGatekeeper( LoggedInGatekeeper.class )` and gwtp will let it show only to registered users all others will be redirected to home/error page.

Anyway, if your site using GAE Users API(userservice) then users will have to go to google's sign-in page for authorization and then return back to your site. Your site's page will be completely refreshed, so using [this technique and jsp](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/webtoolkit/articles/dynamic_host_page.html#template) you can save user's info straight into host jsp-page.

Then in main presenter `onReset()` method get those data using `Dictionary` class or JSNI and do something like this:

```
email = JSNIUtils.getEmail(); 
  // or
  // Dictionary info = Dictionary.getDictionary("info");
  // String email = info.get("email");
loginUrl = JSNIUtils.getLogInUrl();
logoutUrl = JSNIUtils.getLogOutUrl();

if (email != null && logoutUrl != null) {
      // user logged in -> show his email & log out link
    getView().getUserNameAnchor().setText(email);
    getView().getLogInOutAnchor().setText("Log out");
    getView().getLogInOutAnchor().setHref(logoutUrl);
} else if (loginUrl != null) {  
      // unknown user -> show welcome & log in link
    getView().getUserNameAnchor().setText("Hello Stranger");
    getView().getLogInOutAnchor().setText("Log in");
    getView().getLogInOutAnchor().setHref(loginUrl);
} // something else
```

Comment: You can see how to use gwtp gatekeeper http://coffeewithcode.com/2011/08/25/how-to-use-gate-keeper-in-gwt-platform/